# platform independent paid installer

Tags: java, installation, installshield

For my java project i need an installer which is professional like [InstallSheild](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) or [advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/),

Please suggest me some installer which are professional and are paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In past I used InstallAnywhere. Unfortunately I do not remember from which company. But try to google InstallAnywhere and follow a couple of links. All are good.

Answer (score 0):

InstallSheild and InstallAnywhere are both Flexera Software products. You can find them at http://www.flexerasoftware.com

If your interested in a comparable free installation system you should try WIX. You can find them at  http://wixtoolset.org

You will find quite a big learning curve with Wix, but it's just as good if not better than InstallSheild once you've learned how to use it.